# get data from database to select a default value for the drop down box?

Tags: php, sql

So I have a select option for a form... it's part of a echo from php which is why single quotes are used.

```
<select>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
          <option value='6'>6</option>
          <option value='7'>7</option>
          <option value='8'>8</option>
          <option value='9'>9</option>
</select>
```

This is fine and I can select stuff.... however I want to grab the data from the database to set the default value depending on what record it is within the database(I do not want to populate the whole drop down from the database!), however keep the drop down list so that users can still select an other option if the one from the database is different.

I can grab the data from the database using this code, which works... but don't no how to go about getting it to do what I want it to do...

```
<option value=". $row['1'] .">". $row['1'].    "</option>
```

Any ideas?

James

Comment: You want to use selected="selected" http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: echo ($row['1'] == 'thisval) ? ' selected ="selected" ' : '';

Answer (score 1):

```
$selected = 3;
$i = 0;
while( $i < 10 ){
 $i++;

echo "<option value='". $row[ $i ] ."' 
 ".($row[ $i]==$selected?'selected="selected"':"").">". $row[ $i ]."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Where does the "$selected =3;" come in to it? other then that it's still brining up errors.

Comment: thats an example variable for the row you want selected.

Comment: <option value='". $row['1'] ."'".($row['1']==$selected?'selected"':"").">".$row['1']."</option>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
          <option value='6'>6</option>
          <option value='7'>7</option>
          <option value='8'>8</option>
          <option value='9'>9</option>

Comment: I want the default value to be part of the list rather then a separate value

Comment: I added a loop for you. @James Where is your default value coming from?

Comment: it's coming from the database itself? Is that possible?

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { echo then the code i have already sent

Answer (score 0):

First you pull the default value (Which I assume is a users rating of a movie or article or something) from the database using a query, then you loop through the 10 different possible values. When the value matches the default value it will add selected='selected' to the string.

```
echo "<select>";
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT rating FROM movies WHERE user='$user'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
for($i = 1;$i => 10;$i++){
    if($i == $row->rating){
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }else{
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

It does the same thing as the one in the other answer, but this should be far easier to read and understand. (Wether you use the for loop like I do, or the while loop like John does, doesn't matter, they do the same thing)

UPDATE: Delete the echo you are writing in and put in my code, remember to modify the MySQL query.

Comment: thanks, however it needs to go inside an echo. So its like echo..........some stuff........Then the code you gave me.........then back to some more stuff....... as there is more then one element to the form.

Comment: You can add that before and after the code I gave you. When wrapped in <select> tags this will create a drop-down box with the options 1-10 where $row->rating is selected by default

Comment: Right I have gone about this in a different way now. I have created an extra tab le in the database showing the id of the rating and the rating it's self (1-5) I have already created a join between these too table and it has been a success. However I'm no wanting to generate the drop down from this new table and set the default value  as the rating the user has given in the other table. Within the echo. I have looked in to generating the drop down but doesn't seem to want to work inside the echo.

Comment: yeah I did its like this... <select>
for($i = 1;$i => 10;$i++){
    if($i == $row->rating){
        echo <option selected='selected' value='$i'>$i</option>;
    }else{
        echo <option value='$i'>$i</option>;
    }
}
</select>

Comment: Ah, remember to seperate HTML from PHP, like this: `<select><?php ... my code ... ?></select>`

Comment: Still not getting anything... <select>
  <?php 
  $result = mysqli_query($db, SELECT rating FROM movie_rated);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
for($i = 1;$i => 10;$i++){
    if($i == $row->rating){
        echo <option selected='selected' value='$i'>$i</option>;
    }else{
        echo <option value='$i'>$i</option>;
    }
}
   ?> 
</select>

Comment: Well an empty drop down with the two blank options but nothing else.

Comment: Check your Apache log and tell me what you see

Comment: what now? haha it's inside an echo do i need to put the php tags again?

Comment: Eh, I think we misunderstood eachother. If you wrote everything inside an echo, delete that echo and check the updated answer :)

Comment: I can't remove the echo as i'm echoing other data with in the same echo

Comment: Still nothing apart from an empty drop down :(

Comment: Would you mind putting the whole page in pastebin or similar so I can look it through?